First and second component of fft for circle approximation to periodic curve
I wanted to understand how the fast fourier transform work in numpy and for this I tried apply it on $n$ points of an ellipse $t_k = \frac{2\pi}{n-1}k$ with $k=1...n$ $$f_k = f(t_k) = (acos(t_k), bsin(t_k)).$$ Now if the fourier coefficients are given by $$\hat{f}(k):=\frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}f(k)e^{-2\pi i kn},$$ and the points can be computed back from the coefficients using $$f(k):=\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\hat{f}(k)e^{2\pi i kn}$$ I would expect $\hat{f}(0)$ to be the average of ellipse and $\hat{f}(1)$ to be circle approximation of the ellipse.
However in the following code the first fourier component doesn't seem to be the average of the points and the second doesn't seem to approximate the ellipse by a circle.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from typing import List

def main():
    n = 30
    ellipse_points_iter = create_ellipse_points((50,50), 20,10,n)
    ellipse_points_np = np.fromiter(ellipse_points_iter, dtype=complex)

    fourier_coefficients = 1/n*np.fft.fft(ellipse_points_np, 2)
    average = fourier_coefficients[0]
    circle_approx = average + fourier_coefficients[1]*np.exp(2j*np.pi*np.arange(0,n)/n)
    plt.scatter(ellipse_points_np.real, ellipse_points_np.imag)
    plt.scatter(average.real, average.imag)
    plt.scatter(circle_approx.real, circle_approx.imag)
    plt.axis('equal')

def create_ellipse_points(center, a, b, n) -> List[complex]:
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, n)
    parametrization = lambda angle : center[0] + a * np.cos(angle)  + 1j*(center[1] + b * np.sin(angle))
    return map(parametrization, theta)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()

what am I doing wrong?
edit
Indeed as whpowell96 mentions in his answer one has to be careful about the normalization and to be consistant with my equations, one needs ether to use norm="forward" or divide by $1/n$ as I did. However I think the error I get is linked to the $2$ in
fourier_coefficients = 1/n*np.fft.fft(ellipse_points_np, 2)

It seems that this doesn't simply take the first 2 terms of the full array of  coefficients. As a minimal example I tried :
import numpy as np

pts = np.array([0, 1, 1+1j, 1j])
c = np.fft.fft(pts, norm="forward") # c = [0.5+0.5j, -0.5, -0.5j, 0+0j, 0+0j]
c1 = np.fft.fft(pts, norm="forward", n=1) # c1 = [0+0j]
c2 = np.fft.fft(pts, norm="forward", n=2) # c2 = [0.5+0j, -0.5+0j]
c3 = np.fft.fft(pts, norm="forward", n=3) # c3 = [0.6667+0.3333j, -0.622+0.333j, -0..0446-0.16667j]
c4 = np.fft.fft(pts, norm="forward", n=4) # c4 = [0.5+0.5j, -0.5, -0.5j, 0+0j, 0+0j]

From the documentation it seems the coefficient should be cropped so I don't understand why they don't coincide.

I think you simply miss that the input is cropped and not the ouput. For $n=1$ and $n=2$ you get the correct averages or values. For $n=3$ and $n=4$ your input is complex.

@ConvexHull, you are right. fft(a, n) seems to do fft(a[:n]) and not fft(a)[:n] as I expected...
